# Cloudformation fails to create LogStream for newly created LogGroup

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a very simple Cloudformation script which just tries to create a CloudWatch LogGroup and associated LogStream -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Hello World
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Type: String
  EnvName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  AppLogGroup:
    Properties: 
      LogGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - Ref: AppName
          - Ref: EnvName
      RetentionInDays: 7
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  AppLogStream: 
    Properties: 
      LogGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - Ref: AppName
          - Ref: EnvName
      LogStreamName:
        Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - Ref: AppName
          - Ref: EnvName
          - info
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
```

Now this deploys successfully about 50% of the time - but for the other 50%, whilst the LogGroup creates fine, the creation of the LogStream fails with `The specified log group does not exist`; and overall the stack rolls back.

I assume this is because of some kind of failure in the "eventual consistency" within AWS, but am a bit surpised that creation of the LogStream can't wait until the LogGroup has completed.

Am I doing something wrong ? Should I be creating LogStreams in my app rather than the stack ? Does a LogStream get automatically created when you send a first message (doubt it) ? Is there a workaround here ?

TIA.

Comment: Try to add a DependsOn: AppLogGroup declaration to the AppLogStream resource. It will wait for the dependent resource to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually joining strings together to reference the log group in the log stream, you can use `!Ref` for it. With that you also get an implicit dependency of the log stream to the log group, which ensures that CloudFormation will create the log stream after it created the log group. While you could manually specify `DependsOn` to achieve the same, using `!Ref` is the way AWS suggests as best practice. That'd look like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Hello World
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Type: String
  EnvName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  AppLogGroup:
    Properties: 
      LogGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - Ref: AppName
          - Ref: EnvName
      RetentionInDays: 7
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  AppLogStream: 
    Properties: 
      LogGroupName: !Ref AppLogGroup
      LogStreamName:
        Fn::Join:
        - '-'
        - - Ref: AppName
          - Ref: EnvName
          - info
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
```

Comment: I got the message 'The specified log group does not exist' also with dependsOn it doesn't make a difference. After I moved the exact same properties for LogStreamName to a reference it works correct. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a DependsOn: AppLogGroup attribute to the AppLogStream resource. It will wait for the dependent resource to complete.

See 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like just the thing

Comment: Weird tho that i have never had to use this before. Never had to wait for a CodeDeploy app when creating a CodeDeploy deployment group. Never had to wait for vpc/security group etc when creating an EC2 instance. Why CloudWatch so fussy?